# Is the following possible with ndb: query(AdModel.daily_used < AdModel.daily_budget)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to perform a query using ndb in appengine as follows

```
all_adverts = AdModel.query(AdModel.daily_used < AdModel.daily_budget)
```

I am trying to query only items that have not used their daily maximum of their advertising campaign budget. However when I run this I get the following exception:

```
BadValueError: Expected float, got FloatProperty('daily_budget', default=1)
```

Is this simply not possibile with ndb or am I structuring the query incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query needs to scan all of the same kinds which is not the typical usage for datastore.

An easier walkaround is use `ComputedProperty`. Then filter with this property.
Of course this changes will only affects later entity updates.

```
class AdvertModel(ndb.Model):
    daily_used = ndb.FloatProperty()
    daily_budget = ndb.FloatProperty()
    in_money = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.daily_used < self.daily_budget)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup will require use of a custom (composite) index. This increases resources. Why not add a boolean field "daily_under_budget". Every time you update either daily_used or daily_budget you can set this value. You then do not need a custom index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the query mechanism is needs a value on the right hand side of the comparison, not another property.  Its not a limitation of ndb, but how the underlying architecture works.  Hence the error you are getting `BadValueError: Expected float, got FloatProperty('daily_budget', default=1)` .  The other answers are your best bet for the required functionality.